# Eleventy CLI Fatal Error error: sanityClient is not a function in config file '.eleventy.js

Tags: sanity, eleventy

I am trying to link eleventy with sanityClient but getting this error.

> **[11ty] Eleventy CLI Fatal Error: (more in DEBUG output)**
> [11ty] 1. Error in your Eleventy config file '.eleventy.js'. (via EleventyConfigError)
> [11ty] 2. sanityClient is not a function (via TypeError)
> [11ty]
> [11ty] Original error stack trace: TypeError: sanityClient is not a function
> [11ty]     at Object. (C:\Users\DrSanjithSoman\newstoday_11ty.eleventy.js:19:16)
> [11ty]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
> [11ty]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
> [11ty]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
> [11ty]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
> [11ty]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
> [11ty]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
> [11ty]     at requireLocal (C:\Users\DrSanjithSoman\newstoday_11ty\node_modules@11ty\eleventy\src\Util\Require.js:6:10)
> [11ty]     at TemplateConfig.requireLocalConfigFile (C:\Users\DrSanjithSoman\newstoday_11ty\node_modules@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateConfig.js:287:23)
> [11ty]     at TemplateConfig.mergeConfig (C:\Users\DrSanjithSoman\newstoday_11ty\node_modules@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateConfig.js:334:28)

This is my eleventy.js:

```js
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
  // Set the template engine to Nunjucks
  eleventyConfig.setTemplateFormats("njk");

  // Pass-through files and folders
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("src/static");

  // Customize the output folder and input folder
  return {
    dir: {
      input: "src",
      output: "_site"
    }
  };
};

// In your .eleventy.js config file
const sanityClient = require('@sanity/client');
const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: '7jyfzkcq',
  dataset: 'news_data',
  useCdn: true,
});

module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  // Add a filter to retrieve data from Sanity
  eleventyConfig.addFilter('getSanityData', async function(collectionName) {
    const query = `*[_type == '${collectionName}']`;
    const data = await client.fetch(query);
    return data;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

API is different

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/client#api

```js
const { createClient } = require('@sanity/client')

const client = createClient({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  dataset: 'your-dataset-name',
  useCdn: true, // set to `false` to bypass the edge cache
  apiVersion: '2023-05-03', // use current date (YYYY-MM-DD) to target the latest API version
})
```